# TypeError: js_cookie__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_16___default(...) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

In react with axios I send a request to the api, although it is successfully populated, but this error is displayed in the browser console.

```
TypeError: js_cookie__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_16___default(...) is not a function
```

I want to go to the / landing page after the request is done but this does not happen due to an error

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Cookies  from 'js-cookie';

axios.post(url_config.register_url, data)
            .then(res => {
                Cookies.set('access_token', res.data.access_token);
                Cookies.set('refresh_token', res.data.refresh_token);
                decode = jwt_decode(Cookies('access_token'));
                expirationDate(decode.exp);
                history.push('/landing');
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                console.log(err.response)
                
                err.response && err.response.data.username ?
                    setUserNameExist(err.response.data.username) : 
                setUserNameExist('');
                err.response && err.response.data.email ?
                    setEmailIsValid(err.response.data.email) : setEmailIsValid('');
            });
```

With this request, the user can register on the site.
It is very interesting that although the user is stored in the database, but in frontend this error prevents the continuation of the process.

Can you help explain why this error occurs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 decode = jwt_decode(Cookies.get('access_token'));
```